# Nested exponents look too small

Tags: math-mode, fractions

When I type `$e^{\frac{\ln(r)}{2^{j}}}$`, the output is:

[image]

In the exponent, the denominator looks like `2j` (especially in normal font), but it is supposed to look like `2^j`. How can I make the term `2^j` look more distinguishable? More precisely, how to move the letter j "higher", so to speak?

I have tried `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`, but it doesn't give me the desired result.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The denominator of a fraction is always "cramped", by design.  One could work around this, but how about instead, just writing $e^{\ln(r)/2^j}$?

Comment: @RyanReich: Ah! That's an excellent suggestion. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have two options:

- write the fraction in the exponent in inline form (with a `/` rather than with a horizontal bar), with or without pairs of inner parentheses; or
- don't use an exponent and write `\exp ...`.

Your original form and the two alternatives look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$e^{\frac{\ln(r)}{2^{j}}}$

$e^{(\ln(r)/(2^j))}$ or $e^{(\ln r/2^j)}$

$\exp\bigl(\frac{\ln(r)}{2^{j}}\bigr)$
\end{document}
```

For (much) more on the subject of why it may be a good idea to avoid fractions with horizontal bars in inline math expressions and in exponent terms, do check out the posting [Guidelines for typesetting fractions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135725/5001).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also looked at your nice answer in the linked page. It is very informative, and makes me realize that I have been overusing `\frac` and `\dfrac` a lot...

Comment: Perhaps I'd use `$\exp(\ln r/2^j)$`. The symbol is not ambiguous because operators bind more strictly than the division operation symbol. Adding parentheses around `r` may help (although I don't like it).

Comment: @egreg - I agree, those two inner pairs of round parentheses make the whole thing look a bit too busy. I'll post an augmented set of solutions.